# Limit on the WHERE col IN (...) condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using the following code:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE Col IN (123,123,222,....)
```

However, if I put more than ~3000 numbers in the `IN` clause, SQL throws an error.

Does anyone know if there's a size limit or anything similar?!!

Comment: Split the numbers in the IN clause up by groups large enough to process, and async them all at the same time.

Comment: Actaully do not use in - IN is bad because it contains no statistical information. Declare a table valued type of the keys with a primary key (then it has statistical values attached), insert the values there, JOIN between table and that temp table and the query optimizer can do it's work.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Depending on the database engine you are using, there can be limits on the length of an instruction.

SQL Server has a very large limit:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx

ORACLE has a very easy to reach limit on the other side.

So, for large IN clauses, it's better to create a temp table, insert the values and do a JOIN. It works faster also.

Comment: not correct. Max size of SQL instruction or a batch is 65K * (network packet size which is usually 4K) = more then 250 Mb... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx .

Comment: You are damned right on the spot, I complemented the answer. BTW, in ORACLE the limit is VERY easy to reach!.

Comment: According to the forum its not faster in the case of SQLite: 
http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Is-there-a-limit-for-the-number-of-items-in-an-IN-clause-td81307.html

Answer (score 39):

There is a limit, but you can split your values into separate blocks of in()

```
Select * 
From table 
Where Col IN (123,123,222,....)
or Col IN (456,878,888,....)
```

Comment: IN() isn't SARGable. You're much better off pushing your parameters into a temp table or TVP and then using an INNER JOIN.

Comment: what is the limit on above query ? I mean how many IN clauses i can define with OR ?

Comment: @MichaelK.Campbell can you provide some links about "IN() isn't SARGable"? And how significant is it? Perfomance can decrease on 200%?

Comment: @Woland here is [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) about sargable

Comment: However that wiki specifically lists `IN` as a "sargable operator".

Answer (score 14):

Parameterize the query and pass the ids in using a [Table Valued Parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx).

For example, define the following type:

```
CREATE TYPE IdTable AS TABLE (Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)
```

Along with the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp__Procedure_Name
    @OrderIDs IdTable READONLY,
AS

    SELECT *
    FROM table
    WHERE Col IN (SELECT Id FROM @OrderIDs)
```

Comment: I don't know why you are being downvoted because this is a completely valid solution. Although I'd change the `Select Id FROM @OrderIDs` to a join.

Comment: i know this is an old answer, but do you know what happens to your OrderIds? does it remain? or is it simple a temp file?

Comment: @Jason `@OrderIds` is a table-valued parameter. It only exists for the duration of the procedure.

Comment: This is my goto solution. Works well called from javascript, C#. The SQL statement ends up containing multiple INSERTs to the table type instance before the query.

Answer (score 5):

Why not do a where IN a sub-select...

Pre-query into a temp table or something...

```
CREATE TABLE SomeTempTable AS
    SELECT YourColumn
    FROM SomeTable
    WHERE UserPickedMultipleRecordsFromSomeListOrSomething
```

then...

```
SELECT * FROM OtherTable
WHERE YourColumn IN ( SELECT YourColumn FROM SomeTempTable )
```

Comment: Better to do a join to the temp table than a subselect usually.

Comment: Would an exists clause not be even better?

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your version, use a table valued parameter in 2008, or some approach described here:

[Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2005](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html)

Answer (score 1):

For MS SQL 2016, passing ints into the in, it looks like it can handle close to 38,000 records.

```
select * from user where userId in (1,2,3,etc)
```

Comment: what error happens when value is too large?

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify the database engine in question; in Oracle, an option is to use tuples like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE (Col, 1) IN ((123,1),(123,1),(222,1),....)
```

This ugly hack only works in Oracle SQL, see https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/asktom.search?tag=limit-and-conversion-very-long-in-list-where-x-in#9538075800346844400

However, a much better option is to use stored procedures and pass the values as an array.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by simply using ranges

```
WHERE Col >= 123 AND Col <= 10000
```

then removed unwanted records in the specified range by looping in the application code. It worked well for me because I was looping the record anyway and ignoring couple of thousand records didn't make any difference.

Of course, this is not a universal solution but it could work for situation if most values within min and max are required.

Answer (score -4):

You can use tuples like this:
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE (Col, 1) IN ((123,1),(123,1),(222,1),....)

There are no restrictions on number of these. It compares pairs.

Comment: No, in SQL Server you can not. SQL Server uses T-SQL which is not ANSI SQL compliant (neither is any other dialect).

Comment: This ugly hack only works in Oracle SQL, see https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/asktom.search?tag=limit-and-conversion-very-long-in-list-where-x-in#9538075800346844400