# SQL query not taking values more than 2100

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

```
SELECT MachineID, MachineName, count(ID) as Total, sum(Size) as TotalSize 
  FROM Files 
  join Machines on Files.MachineID = Machines.MachineID 
 Where Files.MachineID In(sql.Append(string.Format("@MachineId{0}", i));
 group by Files.MachineID,MachineName
```

now when the machinId count is less than 2100 the query is performed and if it machines go above 2100 an error is thrown 
Error:

> The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Too many parameters were provided in this RPC request. The maximum is 2100.

how do i make increase the limit or just avoid getting this error.. and put values in gridview
thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't say in your example where your "sql" variable comes from but if you manually build your 'IN' list (by building a string with comma delimited values in your IN statement), then all popular relational DBs have a limit to how many values you can specify in a static IN clause.  The database your are using has a 2100 limit.  I believe Oracle is 1000

Comment: basically, i mean when you use a statement like 'SELECT * from myTable where ID IN (1,2,3,4,5,....)'.  What I am saying is that what is inside the paranthesis after the IN keyword, is limited to 2100 or fewer comma delimited values.  Your code 'sql.Append(string.Format("@MachineId{0}", i)' seems to indicate you are building a list of values in a loop.  My hypothesis is that when it breaks that "sql" variable has more than 2100 comma-delimited values

Comment: ok.. yes that is true... i know the problem but how do i get out of it.>? like is there a way to increase the limit or put an exception(but that still wont solve it) or any other cooler way to do this... thanks for the help though.. appreciate it..

Comment: No, there is no way to increase the allowable size of the IN clause.  You may have to look into passing arrays to your SQL or to a stored procedure, or using temp tables to stage the data before using it in your IN clause.  See this thread for ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869753/maximum-size-for-a-sql-server-query-in-clause-is-there-a-better-approach

Comment: hmm... thanks.. ill need to understand this now... i have never used stored procedure... but its good that i do.. any pointers before i do this??

Comment: Are you sure you need to pass in all those `machineId` s manually? No way to `join` them in or select them in another way? Has a user selected 2101+ `machineId` s? Stored routine info is on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html

Answer (score 0):

you could use string functions. In SQL Server your WHERE clause would be something like

```
...WHERE CHARINDEX(':' + <: delimited list of machine IDs> + ':', 
       ':' + CAST(Files.MachineID as VARCHAR(10)) + ':') <> 0
```

The : delimiters are necessary to prevent 100 from matching with 1001, 1002, 2100, etc. A sample query string would be

```
...WHERE CHARINDEX(':1000:1001:1002:1005:', 
       ':' + CAST(Files.MachineID as VARCHAR(10)) + ':') <> 0
```