# SQL server query processor ran out of internal resources

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Query:

```
update mytable 
    set mycol = null
    where id in (
        583048,
        583049,
        ... (50000 more)
)
```

Message:

> The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not
> produce a query plan. This is a rare event and only expected for
> extremely complex queries or queries that reference a very large
> number of tables or partitions. Please simplify the query. If you
> believe you have received this message in error, contact Customer
> Support Services for more information.

My query is very simple,
how should I write it so it works ok?

Comment: I had a very similar problem.  For me it was a simple fix:  Try adding AsParallel() to the Query, just prior to the ToList() or Count().  This option splits the query up and executes them separately, joining the result.  Who know's you may get a performance improvement too.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Insert the list of values into a `#temp` table then use `in` on that.

As explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869753/maximum-size-for-a-sql-server-query-in-clause-is-there-a-better-approach/1869810#1869810) a large number of `IN` values can cause it to run out of stack as they get expanded to `OR`

[See also related connect item](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/521943/the-query-processor-ran-out-of-internal-resources-and-could-not-produce-a-query-plan-with-where-in-and-several-thousand-values)

Comment: Well you can not insert values into a #temp table, it fails with the same error.

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio crashed when the syntax analysis scans the text (too much lines ?). So i used visual studio, cut the list in 10 groups of 10k lines each, and run the query 10 times ...

Comment: @Softion - What fails? The insert to a `#temp` table or using the `#temp` table inside the `in`?

Comment: The insert fails with the same error. Or i missed something ?

Comment: Put the 50000 values in a CSV file and use BULK INSERT to insert the data into a table. Then you can work with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you find this error in SQL Server 2016 or later then try to change the database compatibility level to a lower version 120 or 110, etc. ([link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5279/sql-server-error-query-processor-ran-out-of-internal-resources-and-could-not-produce-a-query-plan/))

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy workarround, split your predicates
Replace this

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE ID like (1,2,3, ... 10000)
```

By

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE ID like (1,2,3, 999) OR 
ID like (1000, .. 1999) OR 
... OR 
ID like (9000, .. 10000)
```

I encountered this error in EF and I fixed it using linqkit 1.2.4 package.     I replaced

```
query.Table.Where(t => ids.contains(id))
```

by

```
var dividedIds = DivideArray(ids.ToArray());
foreach (var batchPortalIds in dividedPortalIds)
{
     predicate.Or(s => batchPortalIds.Contains(s.PortalId.Value));
}
```

Where DivideArray is a function transforming single array to list of array

```
    private List<int[]> DivideArray(int[] originalArray)
        {
            int batchSize = 1000;
    
            List<int[]> dividedArrays = new List<int[]>();
            int currentIndex = 0;
    
            while (currentIndex < originalArray.Length)
            {
                int batchSizeRemaining = Math.Min(batchSize, originalArray.Length - currentIndex);
                int[] batch = new int[batchSizeRemaining];
    
                Array.Copy(originalArray, currentIndex, batch, 0, batchSizeRemaining);
                dividedArrays.Add(batch);
    
                currentIndex += batchSizeRemaining;
            }
    
            return dividedArrays;
        }
```