# SQL which is a query chars limit?

Tags: mysql, sql, character, limit

Does anyone can tell me if is there any chars limit for a query?

I'm wondering cause I need to build up a big routine query and not sure if the query should have a chars limit.

i'm using : MySQL latest version , Apache 2, and PHP

Comment: It depends on the database. What database and version?

Comment: Which RDBMS, and what do you use to connect to your database?  MS-SQL-Server through ADO.NET?  etc?

Comment: @MarkByers. It's very unlikely to exists no matter the database.

Comment: @gdoron : it does exist for SQL Server, it's large, but there is a physical limit related to network packet size see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869753/maximum-size-for-a-sql-server-query-in-clause-is-there-a-better-approach

Comment: @Andrew. I must know, what is the limit? My guess is: too big for yo to care...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a couple good articles I found on the subject.  The second article is actually referred to in the first article.

Maximum length of MySQL query?
http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/8519-maximum-length-mysql-query

Packet too Large - MySQL
http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/Troubleshooting-Problems-with-MySQL-Programs/4/