# StackOverflowException in EF Query with Large Expression Tree

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I'm using EF 5 to perform a select requiring a multitude of `Where` conditions.

One of those conditions is to include only records where a `Code` field is in a list of codes provided by the UI (e.g. SQL translation: `AND Code IN (123, 456)`).

To achieve that, I build an expression tree based on [this post](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t645784-linq-where-clause.html), with the code:

```
static public Expression<Func<TElement, bool>> 
    BuildContainsExpression<TElement, TValue>(
        Expression<Func<TElement, TValue>> valueSelector, 
        IEnumerable<TValue> values)
{
    if (null == valueSelector)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("valueSelector");
    }
    if (null == values) { throw new ArgumentNullException("values"); }

    ParameterExpression p = valueSelector.Parameters.Single();
    if (!values.Any())
    {
        return e => false;
    }

    var equals = 
        values.Select(value => (Expression)Expression.Equal(
            valueSelector.Body, 
            Expression.Constant(value, typeof(TValue))));

    var body = 
        equals.Aggregate<Expression>((accumulate, equal) => 
            Expression.Or(accumulate, equal));

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TElement, bool>>(body, p);
}
```

The code is used like:

```
// List<long> desiredCodes is provided by the UI
containsExpression = LinqToEntitiesUtil.BuildContainsExpression<MyClass, long>
    (my => my.Code, desiredCodes);    

// In the actual code there are several other Where conditions as well
var matching = ctx.MyClasses.Where(containsExpression).Select(my => my);
```

This works perfectly when `desiredCodes` is reasonably sized.  However, when the list contains a little over 1000 codes, I get a `StackOverflowException` the moment the `matching` iterator is evaluated.

**Questions**

Is there another way to implement the *Contains* requirement that is not vulnerable to a StackOverflowException?

Is there an upper limit on the size of the generated SQL imposed by SQL (SQL Server 2012)?

Comment: 64K statement size limit.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869753/maximum-size-for-a-sql-server-query-in-clause-is-there-a-better-approach  followed by issues that occur before. perhaps stacksize issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We experience the same problem, and after I've analyzed the bug, the only workaround as of now is to write the query manually (e.g. generate the IN (...) by string.Join() or something), since EF seems to build the statement by recursively walk the expression three.