How to avoid "SQLServerException: The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not produce a query plan."
I'm issuing the following query, via java.sql.Statement.executeQuery():
SELECT columns  FROM Table1, Table2
WHERE ( ColX IN (...) OR ColX IN (...) OR ... OR ColX IN (...) )
  AND Table1.Col1 = Table2.Col2

There are 89 (…); each (…) contains 1000 integer ID's except the last, which contains 476.  So, 89,476 integer ID’s in the query.
I get back:

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not produce a query plan. This is a rare event and only expected for extremely complex queries or queries that reference a very large number of tables or partitions. Please simplify the query. If you believe you have received this message in error, contact Customer Support Services for more information.

I've seen suggestions here to use a #temp table, or Table-Valued Parameters.  However, if I paste the query into SQL Server Management Studio, it runs fine and I get back 1937 rows.  So, it seems like this can work in some circumstances.
Therefore, my question is:  Is there anything that can be tweaked to allow this query to run when issued from Java?
Background:  I have a customer hitting this who's running a back-level version of our product.  We support multiple DBMS's.  While we could consider changing the code to use a #temp table or TVP for a future release, we need to resolve it with minimal changes for the older releases.  I'm using SQL Server 2022; not sure offhand what the customer is running.

You could split your query into unions of different ORs, perhaps it might help the issue and still be relatively portable to other DBMSes. Although, i'm very wary of any system that have need to do the "IN (...)" stuff where "..." contains more than 10 values, it's usually a sign of bad design, so you might wanna look at redesigning it to use something else entirely, instead of slapping a TVP on it and calling it a day

One idea would be to return all the rows in the table and use Java code to select the 1,937 rows.

Don't do it that way, put the 89000 values into a temp table then join.

More information on this, looks like it was an older article but perhaps still applicable
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5279/sql-server-error-query-processor-ran-out-of-internal-resources-and-could-not-produce-a-query-plan/

Thanks, @ViaTech - that looked promising.  Adding a hint is an easy change.  I appended:
OPTION (USE HINT ('FORCE_LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION'))
Unfortunately, that just changed the exception text thrown in Java - although as before, it worked fine in SSMS.
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Query processor could not produce a query plan because of the hints defined in this query. Resubmit the query without specifying any hints and without using SET FORCEPLAN.

I have not personally used this DB (in Prod) and have not hit this error before. All hints appear that it is some type of memory/performance issue with the amount of data being processed (although it honestly doesn't seem too much for issues logically thinking, millions of rows sure, thousands shouldn't be an issue). I think you need to discover why the individual query is slow (and poor) and figure out indexing and performance enhancements...something is wrong with the query in my opinion, but I can't tell what is making it "wrong" without seeing full schema and indexes

Could it possibly run if that where clause condition is used as a join condition instead?

Are the values distinct? I'm guessing each of the lists is generated somewhat independently.

This answer comes from a former SQL Server developer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1869810/1322268 It also possibly explains why the behavior is different on a test setup.

Doubt any hints will help you, besides kicking the can further down the road, sql server just doesn't like so many ORs and INs, so likely the parser gives up already. Did you try UNIONizing?

@shawnt00 - Yes, they're distinct.  It's only bundled into multiple clauses with no more than 1000 entries in each due to an Oracle limitation on the number of entries in an 'IN' clause.
I had read that other answer before posting, along with the Erland Sommarskog article it referenced.
"different on a test setup" - My thinking is that if the query works in SSMS, perhaps there's something different that the JDBC driver is doing, and understanding that might suggest an approach.

@siggemannen - Kicking the can further down the road is exactly what I'm trying to do.  I'm looking for a simple patch I can make to our back-level release to get this one customer in good shape.  A rewrite of the code to use one of the other solutions suggested for this issue would be going into our next release.

It's not clear what kinds of changes are easy to make. Is this in a stored procedure? Can you split off some of the values into a union? (Since it might be significant for performance maybe there's a threshold on the number that should apply pushing some off to the union.)

@shawnt00
Not a stored procedure.  Dynamically generated SQL, generated as a string and passed to java.sql.Statement.executeQuery().
Since we support multiple DBMS's, "easy changes" are things that wouldn't require a major rewrite which is SQL Server specific.  OTOH, I suppose if we're going to give this customer a patch, we don't need to worry about other DBMS's.

Use a Table Valued Parameter, or a table variable or temp table, and just do a normal join. Large IN clauses are in any case a serious performance issue and should be avoided.
Also use explicit join syntax, not the ancient comma-join as it's much more readable.
SELECT
  columns
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Col1 = t2.Col2
WHERE ColX IN (
    SELECT v.ColX
    FROM @tvp v
);

TVPs are supported on fairly old versions of SQL Server, and you can always make a real table instead. There is no other option. Do not be tempted to mess around with server memory, it's going to blow up either way with so many values. I'm also suspicious of what is quite clearly SQL injection, as it's not possible to pass so many parameters.

If you really really really want to keep it as 90,000 values injected into your query then a small rewrite might work better.
SELECT
  columns
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Col1 = t2.Col2
WHERE ColX IN (
    SELECT v.ColX
    FROM (VALUES
      (1),
      (2),
      (3),
      -- etc
    ) v
);




As specified in the question, I'm looking for a way to make it work without a major rewrite.  The same query works if plugged in to SQL Server Management Studio.


Not passing lots of parameters.  It's resolving nested group memberships; it's generating the query as text based on the results from previous queries.




So what do you want? There is no magic switch to make such a query always work, you are always going to be at risk of it failing because of the way the compiler works. 2. Sounds like dynamic SQL, so comes to the same thing. But see edit.


I tried the rewrite; it didn't help.
