# what is the maximum value we can use with IN operator in sql

Tags: sql

what is the maximum value we can use with IN operator in sql

Comment: Whatever the maximum value that is allowed for the data types you are using on the database you are using.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069415/limit-on-the-where-col-in-condition