# Manage or split a long list of SQL IN parameters with Hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate

In some SQL variants (notably [Oracle](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_maximum_number_of_sql_in_list_values.htm)), the number of parameters one can pass to an `IN` statement is limited. I.e. the following wouldn't work;

```
select * from molecules where id in (atom_1, atom_2, atom_3, ... atom_785534);
```

Multiple solutions have been suggested, including [using a temporary table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069415/limit-on-the-where-col-in-condition) or [split the parameters into smaller groups](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=937469).

What is the optimal solution for an ORM, specifically Hibernate 5+? As far as I can tell, it's not possible to create a temporary table with Hibernate and looping through chunks is not ideal, particularly when you may have multiple lists of paramaters that run the risk of overflowing the limit.

Comment: Does anything stop you from creating a permanent table and emptying it every time you're done using it?

Comment: It's not particularly great to have a util table lying around for both encapsulation reasons and maintenance. Plus it's limited to only one list of parameters.

Comment: You could easily extend that table with a paramType like column and use it to store an arbitrary amount of lists. But I see your point. Still it might be worth considering