# LinQ to SQL throws Stackoverflow exception when using Any()

Tags: c#, postgresql, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

I'm using a LinQ query that looks like this

```
public List<TEntity> GetEntities<TEntity>(int[] ids)
{
    var someDbSet = new DbSet<TEntity>();

    var resultQ = someDbSet.Where(t => !ids.Any() || ids.Contains(t.ID)); //<= crashing line

    return resultQ.toList();
}
```

It usually works, but for some case when ids size is ~ 7000 items it crashes.
The thrown exception message is "Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.".
It has no stack trace or InnerException.

I also get this info: "EntityFramework.pdb not loaded... contains the debug information required to find the source for the module EntityFramework.dll"

Is this a known bug or can someone explain why it doesn't work when the array is bigger?

I'm using .NET Framework 4.5, EntityFramework 6.1.3, EntityFramework6.Npgsql 3.0.3

Comment: Any requires parameters.  Why not use != null?  c# is not VB.Net where you need to use Not Nothing.

Comment: @jdweng This applies to `List`s also. So you could have an empty list that is not null

Comment: Yes.  Linq sometimes returns a list with no items.  So often my pass fail criteria with linq is resultQ.Count() > 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we pass an array with only two values `int[] ids = {1, 2}` to your method `GetEntities` EntityFramework will generate the next query:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
...
FROM [dbo].[Entity] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM  (SELECT 
        1 AS [C0]
        FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 
        1 AS [C0]
        FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable2]) AS [UnionAll1]
)) OR (1 = [Extent1].[Id]) OR (2 = [Extent1].[Id])
```

If we increase the number of elements in `ids` array this query becomes more complex with more levels of nestings. I think that EntityFramework uses some recursive algorithm to generate SQL-code for `!ids.Any()` expression. When the number of elements in `ids` array increases the depth of the recursion also increases. Therefore it generates `StackOverflowException` when the number of elements in `ids` array (and also the depth of the recursion) is large.

If we delete `!ids.Any()` expression the next query will be generated:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
...
FROM [dbo].[Entity] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Id] IN (1,2)
```

Such query does not generate `StackOverflowException` when the number of elements in the `ids` array is large. Therefore it would be better to extract `!ids.Any()` expression out of LINQ query:

```
public List<TEntity> GetEntities<TEntity>(int[] ids)
{
    var someDbSet = new DbSet<TEntity>();

    if (!ids.Any())
        return someDbSet.ToList();

    var resultQ = someDbSet.Where(t => ids.Contains(t.ID));
    return resultQ.toList();
}
```

You should also take to account that there is a limitation on number of items for `WHERE IN` condition: [Limit on the WHERE col IN (...) condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069415/limit-on-the-where-col-in-condition).

---

ionutnespus wrote:

> Yes, extracting the condition outside Where() is working. Still, I
>   couldn't find any explanation why EF would use such a complicated
>   algorithm for such a simple condition. Any thoughts on that?

I've decided to answer this question by extending this post because the asnwer is large and contains code.

I don't know for sure why EF generates such complex query but I've made some research and here are my thoughts. If we modify your `GetEntites` method and use next condition in LINQ query:

```
someDbSet.Where(t => !ids.Any(i => i == 3) || ids.Contains(t.ID));
```

the next SQL-query will be generated if `ids = {1, 2}`:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
...
FROM [dbo].[Entity] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ( NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 AS [C1]
    FROM (
        SELECT 1 AS [C0] FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1] WHERE 3 = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 1 AS [C0] FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable2] WHERE 3 = 2
        ) AS [UnionAll1]
)) OR (1 = [Extent1].[Id]) OR (2 = [Extent1].[Id])
```

Here you can see that `NOT EXISTS` condition contains two subqueries each of which checks if the next element of the `ids` array equals required value. I think that it is logical to use `NOT EXISTS` SQL-condition to represent `Any()` method. But why does EF generates one subquery for each array element? In my opinion EF does so because because EF Team tried to write algorithm that generates queries that are not depend on database type. But this is only my opinion. May be it would be better to ask this question EF Team on [github](https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/tree/master/src/EntityFramework).

Comment: Yes, extracting the condition outside `Where()` is working. Still, I couldn't find any explanation why EF would use such a complicated algorithm for such a simple condition. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: I've extended my post and added my thouths why EF generates such complex query.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this?

```
    public List<TEntity> GetEntities<TEntity>(int[] ids)
    {
        var someDbSet = new DbSet<TEntity>();
        var resultQ = new List<your_list_type>();
        foreach( var id in ids) {
          resultQ.Add(someDbSet.Where(prm => prm.ID == id).FirstOrDefault());
}
        return resultQ;

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

As per your error message, The exception that is thrown when the execution stack overflows because it contains too many nested method calls.
As MSDN

The default maximum size 2 gigabytes (GB) of an array.

In a 64-bit environment, you can avoid the size restriction by setting the enabled attribute of the gcAllowVeryLargeObjects configuration element to true in the run-time environment.

Moreover your ids exceeds to 2 gb limits. i think this might be the cause

Comment: We know that `ids` is an `int[]`. We know that it errors at 7000 elements. Therefore, the `ids` array is about 28KB, or 1% of 2GB. That isn't the issue.

Comment: your 7000 elements exceed the array size . e.g :  ids[6999] = 9999999999 something like that

Comment: I don't have any idea what you are trying to say, but it has nothing to do with this issue.