# How to move a subset of a table from one server to another using Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I think I am facing a common problem when moving data between two servers but I can't find a good solution. I have two servers: `server1` and `server2`. I want to move a subset of a table in `server1` to a table in `server2`. I have the following tables (source and sink tables have the same schema):

1. `server1.dbo.source` - Contains ID + other columns.
2. `server2.dbo.sink` - Contains ID + other columns (same schema as `source` table).
3. `server2.dbo.utilizedIds` - Contains one column with list of IDs I would like to move.

If I could reference both servers in the same query, the data that I am trying to move from `server1` to `server2` could be described by this SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM server1.dbo.source 
WHERE server1.dbo.source.id IN (SELECT * FROM server2.dbo.utilizedIds)
```

What I am trying to achieve is to only move `IDs` that I need. These `IDs` are dynamic and stored in a table in my destination server. I am doing this because I need a really small subset of the source table (I need thousands of rows out of billions). So far, these are the solutions that I have found and the reasons why I can't use them or I wouldn't like to use them:

1. Copy all the data into a temp table in `server2` and perform the filtering there - Moving this much data every time I need to update my sink is not feasible.
2. Perform a delta insert of the source table into `server2` and then filter this table - While this would be more performant than option 1, I really don't want to incur the cost of storing billions of rows when I only need thousands.
3. Create temp tables/persistent tables in `server1` and insert the `IDs` into this table, then filter using standard SQL - I am not the owner of `server1`, I cannot create tables or stored procedures. The temp table option was promising but temp tables don't persist across activities.
4. Create a dynamic query and pass the `IDs` as a string to the `SELECT` statement. Something like this: `SELECT * FROM server1.dbo.source WHERE id IN ('ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3' ...)` - So far, this is my best solution. However, [SQL statements have a length and parameter limit, and this is not a good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069415/limit-on-the-where-col-in-condition)

To me, this seems like a common use case. What is the best practice or correct solution to this problem? Building my query using strings feels like a hack and not something ADF was designed for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `data flow` you can use the `Join` transformation to get the matching rows of server 1 data (dbo.source) with the IDs of server 2 (dbo.utilizedIds).

**Example:**

**Input:**

Server1 – dbo.source

[image]

Server2- dbo.utilizedIds

[image]

**Data flow:**

1. Add a `source` transformation in data flow and connect it to the source dataset (server1 dbo.source)

[image]

2. Add another `source` transformation and connect it to server2 Id’s table (server2 dbo.utilizedIds)

[image]

3. Add `Join` transformation and perform an inner join between source1 (server1 dbo.source) and source2 (server2 dbo.utilizedIds) with join condition as Id.

[image]

[image]

4. `Join` transformation will pull all the columns from the left and right streams for the matched rows. To remove duplicate columns, use select transformation and remove the columns.

[image]

[image]

5. Add `sink` transformation and connect it to the sink table (server2 dbo.sink) to load the source rows matched Ids to the sink.

[image]

Comment: Great solution. My only concern though is the performance of this approach. I assume that the first import (source1) pulls all the rows in the table? If so, every time I ran this pipeline I would pull billions of rows. Is that the correct interpretation?

Comment: Yes, it will pull all records unless you have any condition specified (you cannot write cross-server queries here).